# Using FreeImage with Xcode

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, dylib, freeimage

I'm writing an application in which I want to use free image to load files. I am on MacOSX 10.8.2 and I am using the mac ports version of free image. I had it working, but when I tried putting it on another computer without the port, it wouldn't run because it didn't have the files. The macports version comes with a dylib, can I use that to run it without downloading the port? If I can how would I compile it with the project because I have tried linking it as a Binary Library, but I can't include the files. Any help would be appreciated, as I have bee at this for a few hours now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can actually build the FreeImage library as a static library. Unfortunately, the downloadable source from the http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html website uses makefiles that are expecting to use the older SDKs for Xcode3.

I actually updated the Makefile.osx to build with Xcode4 using the 10.7 SDK and posted the change to https://gist.github.com/AhiyaHiya/5105571

You should be able to run this make from Terminal.app and create your .dylib and .a files for your needs.